# Can we use TLS 1.1 or higher with the Amazon Web Services Mechanical Turk API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, tls1.2, mechanicalturk

We've had some outbound and inbound API services from Salesforce to Amazon Mechanical Turk that have worked fine for 5-6 years. Salesforce disabled TLS 1.0 on Oct 21 so now they fail.

I've not seen if the Amazon Mechanical Turk API supports TLS 1.1 or higher and, if so, what changes need to be made to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Mechanical Turk Requester API currently supports TLS 1.2 (as well as 1.0 and 1.1). You can verify using the [SSL Labs' Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com).

Comment: Not according to our test today from Salesforce.

Get "10:00:24.0 (476523271)|FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client."

According to the Mturk folks someone spoke to last week it won't be supported until the end of the year despite that that link shows.

Comment: Do you know what version of the SDK you're using? Older versions (particularly those not part of the AWS SDK) might be aimed at an endpoint that doesn't support TLS. For example, the CLI tools uses mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com, which only supports TLS 1.0.

Comment: Yes its an older version of SDK we are using. Did not want to upgrade until TLS 1.1+ supported. Will try new version, Amazon also sent message today indicating TLS 1.1 supported with "new" SDK.